# Hide Div with empty Product Module Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, hide

maybe someone can help me? I tried a few codes from stackoverflow already, but no one is working correctly.

https://espressoperfetto.de/slayer-espresso-v3-espressomaschine-single

On this Page - above the Footer we have the same Postmodule in Uncode Wordpress Theme like here: https://espressoperfetto.de/stone-espresso-plus-schwarz/

The Module should show the related products, anyway, some products are not configured yet but the Module should be active. Is it possible to hide the Module, if its saying "nothing found."? The hole Div with the Heading "Passende Produkte entdecken" should be hidden. Many thanks in advance! (Java noob, who wants to learn).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you have solved the problem, right? You can anwser your own question so other might learn from it